# UDP Packet Loss

Tags: ethernet, performance

I have an application on a PC that sends **10 UDP packets** to an Arduino Portenta board.  When sending packets with no delay, half of them are lost.  Wireshark shows the packets are correctly sent by the PC.  If I busy-wait 1ms between each message on the PC, the Arduino receives everything.

I tried to disable the processing done when receiving a message, but it doesn't help.

I know UDP is not a reliable protocol.  Still, having half the packets lost while the PC is directly connected to the Arduino is surprising.  I'm only trying to send 10 packets!

Is there an option to increase the receive buffer?  I would have tried increasing SO_RCVBUF.

Any other idea?

Thank you

Comment: Obvious "other idea": TCP - nothing is lost and if the network doesn't have capacity, you can't flood it like with UDP. Another one: bigger packets, less often. But nothing useful

Comment: The use case is not appropriate for TCP.

Answer (score 2):

UDP does not guarantee delivery.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

> It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes the user's program to any unreliability of the underlying network; there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering, or duplicate protection.

You have chosen a protocol that is inherently not guaranteed to be delivered, and thus you have to work around it by:

- slowing transmission
- accepting that not all packets will be received
- some other mechanism

Comment: The PC is directly connected to the Arduino, and I only send 10 packets.  Would that mean only 5 packets are buffered by the Arduino?

Comment: @Simon It could indicate that the rate at which the Arduino can remove packets from the buffer is such that it can only keep up with a slower rate. Possibly only one packet is buffered, but by the time you have processed that you have lost the next one but the third can be received OK. And so on.